# Rails searchkick query for multi fields don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I want to do a searchbar to search a term in many fields of my model.
For now I have this code :

```
@query_search = "#{params[:search]}"
products = Campaign.search query: {match: {name: @query_search}}, fields: [{owner:  @query_search}], misspellings: {distance: 2}
```

the result works only on the `name` fields (and only on the exact case). the `fields: [{owner:  @query_search}]` change nothing.
I tried to do things like this :

```
products = Campaign.search query: {match: {name: @query_search, brief: @query_search}}, fields: [{owner:  @query_search}], misspellings: {distance: 2}
```

but no result, misspellings don't work either in any case.

So, Anybody has an idea? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The `query` option tells Searchkick to use the exact query you provide, so the other options will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

What Andrew said, and just try running the regular search:

```
products = Campaign.search(
  params[:search],
  misspellings: {distance: 2}
)
```

It should generate a query with multi_match across all fields by default anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `elasticsearch` `cross_fields` or `query_string` feature to search in more than one fields with one term. Unfortunately `searchkick` does not support it and you have to do it by yourself.

You can follow the example of my answer to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34266548/2767026).