# Searchkick not searching multiple terms when specify fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, searchkick

Can anyone provide advice on the following please?

I'm using searchkick / elasticsearch and would like to search for a key term or terms across multiple fields (name, manufacturer). So for example if im looking for a product called "myproduct" made my "somemanufacturer" i'd expect to see this result appear if I search either "myproduct", "somemanufacturer" or "myproduct somemanufacturer" as both these terms are included either in name or manufacturer fields.

My problem is the following:

```
@products = Product.search query
```

Allows all the search terms listed above and returns expected result however as soon as I add

```
@products = Product.search query, fields: [:name, :manufacturer_name]
```

It will only return a result for "myproduct", or "somecompany", but not "myproduct somecompany".

Now this isn't a big deal as I can remove the fields option entirely BUT I need to utilise searchkicks word_start for the name field. So my final query is something like this:

```
@products = Product.search query, fields: [{name: :word_start}, :manufacturer_name]
```

I'd like users to search for the 1st string of the product and be able to enter a manufacturer too eg "myprod somecompany" unfortunately this returns zero results when I was hoping it would return the product named myproduct, made by somecompany.

Am i missing something really obvious here? I can change add

```
operator: 'or'
```

but really i want to be able to part search on the name, add additional terms and if both are present for a particular record it gets returned.

heres my model code also

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 searchkick word_start: [:name]
end
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm with the same exact problem, have you figured out?

Comment: Figured out, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

If all of your fields share the same analyzer, you can use `elasticsearch` feature called `cross_fields`. If it is not the case, you can use `query_string`. Unfortunately `searchkick` does not support `cross_fields` and `query_string` yet. So, you have to do it by yourself.

**Index (different analyzers)**

```
searchkick merge_mappings: true, mappings: {
  product: {
    properties: {
      name: {
        type: 'string',
        analyzer: 'searchkick_word_start_index',
        copy_to: 'grouped'
      },
      manufacturer_name: {
        type: 'string',
        analyzer: 'default_index',
        copy_to: 'grouped'
      },
      grouped: {
        raw: {type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search with cross_fields**

```
@products = Product.search(body: {
  query: {
     multi_match: {
                  query: query,
                  type: "cross_fields",
                  operator: "and",
                  fields: [
                      "name",
                      "manufacturer_name",
                      "grouped",
                  ]
              }
         }
}
```

**Search with query_string**

```
@products = Product.search(body: {
  query: {
      query_string: {
                  query: query,
                  default_operator: "AND",
                  fields: [
                      "name",
                      "manufacturer_name",
                      "grouped",
                  ]
              }
         }
}
```

**Update**
- Changed my answer to the use of different analyzers and multi fields following the this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34271927/2767026).

Unfortunately passing the query to `elasticsearch` by yourself you lose `searchkick` features like highlight and conversions, but, you can still do it, adding it to the `elasticsearch` query.

**Adding hightlight to the query**

```
@products = Product.search(body: {
  query: {
    ...
  }, highlight: {
    fields: {
      name: {},
      manufacturer_name: {}
    }
  }
```

**Adding conversions to the query**

```
@products = Product.search(body: {
  query: {
    bool: {
      must: {
        dis_max: {
          queries: {
            query_string: {
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      },
      should: {
        nested: {
          path: 'conversions',
          score_mode: 'sum',
          query: {
            function_score: {
              boost_mode: 'replace',
              query: {
                match: {
                  "conversions.query": query
                }
              },
              field_value_factor: {
                field: 'conversions.count'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: where did you get the 'searchkick_word_start_index' and 'default_index'???

Comment: theyre function names within index_options.rb of the searchkick github code

Comment: more specifically theyre names of analyzers that searchkick pre-defined

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is to combine the fields into one with the `search_data` method.

```
class Product
  def search_data
    {
      full_name: "#{manufacturer_name} #{name}"
    }
  end
end
```

Be sure to reindex afterwards. Then use full name to search. All of Searchkick's features will continue to work.