# Elasticsearch indexing multi_field with array field

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and I'm trying to create a multi_field index with `string` and `array of strings` fields. With the `string` fields it's all working great but when I try to get some results when they are inside an array, it returns an empty one.

**My data:**

```
{
  "string_field_one": "one",
  "string_field_two": "two",
  "array_of_strings_field": [
     "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"
  ]
}
```

**Mappings:**

```
{
    "string_field_one" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "analyzer": "snowball",
         "copy_to": "group"
     },
    "string_field_two" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "analyzer": "snowball",
         "copy_to": "group"
     },
    "array_of_strings_field" : {
         "type" : "string",
         "analyzer": "keyword",
         "copy_to": "group"
    }
    "group" : {
        "type": "multi_field"
    }
}
```

**Search:**

```
 "body": {
          "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                  "query": "one two 2010",
                  type: "cross_fields",
                  operator: "and",
                  fields: [
                      "string_field_one",
                      "string_field_two",
                      "array_of_strings_field",
                      "group"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
```

**Expecting:**

- Searching by `one`, `two`, or `2010` should return the result
- Searching by `one two` should return the result
- Searching by `one two 2010` should return the result
- Searching by `one two 2008` should not return the result

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross_fields has the constraint all fields should have the same [search analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_cross_field_literal_and_analysis) or rather all the query terms should occur in fields with same search analyzer. Which is not the case here.
You would need to  use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) for the above case:

Example:

```
"body": {
           "query": {
              "query_string": {
                  "query": "one two 2010",
                  "default_operator": "AND",
                  "fields": [
                      "string_field_one",
                      "string_field_two",
                      "array_of_strings_field",
                      "group"
                  ]

              }
          }
   }
```

Comment: Have updated my question, using `copy_to` solved most of my problems, but now even changing to `query_string` the field `array_of_strings_field` that should match the exact result are matching similar word yet.

Comment: could you update the question with the new query i.e what role does group.raw play in the query ?

Comment: Apparently was doing something wrong, it is all working now. Thank you!