# Use Boolean Operator(mini-language) in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I had implement SearchKick in my rails app. That app holds all the feature of searching that a recruiter app can have. I had working on this app for last 2 years and my searching query is written well enough to hold the aggregated data and some conditional clauses as well.

Now I want to implement "mini-language"(Boolean Operator) that is supported by elastic search using query_string.

Query String Supported Boolean Operator:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax

I want to use `query_String` with my existing SearchKick query. I know I can use Advanced Search but for this I would have to replace my current SearchKick query with an ElasticSearch query. I don't want to do that because it is a big change for my project which is live and has 1000+ of users.

I just want to adjust `query_string` in seachKick query in some way without having to replace it with ES query.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
But, if I understood the situation correctly, Searchkick maintainers decided to not support current behavior.

They mentioned it here:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/97

and here:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1494

But, some workarounds may help you well enought.
You may do something like this:

```
Product.search body: {query: {query_string: {query: 'white shoes and water washable', default_field: 'product_description'}}}
```

I found it in this conversation:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/1390#issuecomment-596657334

Or, you may just combine the needed fields into one for the `search_data` method. Which maybe even easier, but probably a more robust solution.

Please, see the reference below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51778715/2703618